# Web rendering - Trying to figure out the different kinds of rendering

Tags: web-development, web-applications, websites

I have a background as a full stack web developer, but didn't code professionally speaking for about 8 years, now focusing on technical and/or functional analysis. In the meanwhile, many things changed of course, and I'm now trying to "refresh" my understanding of how modern web can be rendered, so that I can still at least understand what devs are talking about.

#### What I understand pretty well (I guess)

Static rendering (like in the "good old days"), server rendering with things like PHP, ASP, Coldfusion and so on, Client-side rendering and clients becoming fatter and fatter, up to things like angular, react or vue.js

#### Where it becomes blurry

I basically have a hard time fully understanding the table that can be found at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web) :

[image]

**What I think I understand from it:**

Server-rendering = PHP,ASP,JSP,ColdFusion,...
Full CSR = Vue.js, Angular, React,...

**What I don't get exactly:**

What happens server-side/client-side in the 3 middle columns... where does "server" end and "client" start? What is exactly fetched, and when, by client from server? How "dynamic" is the data shown to the user, "from when" is it dated (runtime? build time? ... ?)
My goal is not to start developing again (at least not professionally) with these technologies/concepts, I just would like a better conceptual understanding of them.

Comment: That is Google's categorization of web applications. That is not an industry standard definition. Answering this question is a very broad topic. You might find [From URL to Interactive](https://alistapart.com/article/from-url-to-interactive/) a good read. It is a multi-part blog series, if that gives you an idea of what an answer to this question would look like.

Comment: Seems interesting indeed, will give it a read. I knew my question was maybe too broad, maybe after the reading I'll be able to ask more narrow question(s). Is there any "industry standard" definition, or attempt of definition? I'm reading a lot of articles where for example "Server-Side rendering" seems to be used for many different concepts, and I'm wondering whether these concepts have an "official" name...

Comment: They do not, unfortunately. Web apps are a spectrum of server side and client side logic, from business logic to rendering.